# Cannot modify global Label in Tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-label

I am simply trying to make a `Radiobutton` GUI using `tkinter`. In which I want to change/replace the "Select your toppings" `Label` (`myLabel`) every time the user selects any `Radiobutton` with that `Radiobutton` name. So, the error which I am facing is instead of replacing that label a new label is created just below even though I am using a global `Label`.

```py
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

Toppings = [
    ["Pepperoni", "Pepperoni"],
    ["Cheese", "Cheese"],
    ["Mushroom", "Mushroom"],
    ["Onion", "Onion"]
]

pizza = StringVar()
pizza.set("Select your toppings")

for topping, value in Toppings:
    Radiobutton(root, text = topping, variable = pizza, value = value). pack(anchor = W)

myLabel = Label(root, text = pizza.get())
myLabel.pack()

def clicked(value):
    global myLabel
    myLabel.grid_forget()
    myLabel = Label(root, text = value)
    myLabel.pack()


myButton = Button(root, text="CLick me!", command = lambda: clicked(pizza.get()))
myButton.pack()



root.mainloop()
```

[image: Image of my code output goes here]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.config` to configure a particular widget option (and no need to use `global` in this case anyways) (and the explanation of why overwriting it didn't work is because you need to remove it from the `Tcl` by calling `.destroy` if you want to do it that way but that is unnecessary):

```py
def clicked(value):
    myLabel.config(text=value)
```

Also I would suggest following PEP 8 and not have space around `=` if it is used in keyword arguments, also variable names should be in `snake_case`. And don't use `*` when importing a module, import only what you need.

Further improvements:

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Label, Radiobutton, StringVar

toppings = [
    "Pepperoni",
    "Cheese",
    "Mushroom",
    "Onion"
]

root = Tk()

topping_var = StringVar(value='Select your topping')

for topping in toppings:
    Radiobutton(root, text=topping, variable=topping_var, value=topping).pack(anchor='w')

myLabel = Label(root, textvariable=topping_var)
myLabel.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

You don't need to use a button, just set the variable as the `textvariable` for the `Label` and that is it